# getimagesize() function does not working for some images

Tags: php, getimagesize

`getimagesize()` function returns `FALSE` for some images.

**Example:** 
[image]

```
$path1 = getcwd().'/images/communities/29/eagle-ridge-26.jpg';
$vals_arr1 = getimagesize($path1);

$path2 = 'http://homematrix.oskyserver.com/images/communities/29/
                                               eagle-ridge-26.jpg';
$vals_arr2 = getimagesize($path2);
```

In both cases, it returns `FALSE`, I have searched, but not found a good solution yet.

Comment: Please check the path(print $path1), whether it is correct or not?

Comment: I have used file_exists($path1) before using getimagesize($path1), file_exists returns true. but getimagesize returns false

Comment: yes you are correct, your example is not working in my local system. I will check, if i get the result then let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Its working :

You must provide the absolute path:

For example:

```
$path1 = getcwd().'/images/logo.jpg';
$vals_arr1 = getimagesize($path1);
echo "<pre>";var_dump($vals_arr1);echo "</pre>";

$path2 = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'images/logo.jpg';
$vals_arr2 = getimagesize($path2);
echo "<pre>";var_dump($vals_arr2);echo "</pre>";
```

Result:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(288)
  [1]=>
  int(70)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  string(23) "width="288" height="70""
  ["bits"]=>
  int(8)
  ["channels"]=>
  int(3)
  ["mime"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(288)
  [1]=>
  int(70)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  string(23) "width="288" height="70""
  ["bits"]=>
  int(8)
  ["channels"]=>
  int(3)
  ["mime"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it is not working with the image I have given there. Like I explained in the question it is only not work with some images, can you try the example image and let me know if that works for you. Thanks

Comment: @Akhil5 This code is correct "$path1 = getcwd().'/images/communities/29/eagle-ridge-26.jpg';
$vals_arr1 = getimagesize($path1);" But please print the "$path1" and check the path is correct? Please try. The second one is surly not work.

Comment: Yes. the path is correct and file_exists() returns true.

Comment: Oh Sad.. But my local system work correctly. Okay i will check and let you know.

Comment: that means you have used the same image I have used and correctly worked in your local system ? If not can you try using the same image in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is with the image itself and getimagesize() just will not work with that image. Try opening up the image in Photoshop or similar program, make a change to the image size (for instance), and save the image with a new name. Then try using the script with that new image. This worked for me. All the images from one file on my computer were processing with my script using getimagesize(), except for one image. Once I slightly changed the file and saved it and tried the script again it worked without any errors.